# How to correctly format an alpha-numerical in an exported csv file opened in excel

Tags: excel, csv

On exporting a csv file and opening it in microsoft excel, I find there is a column containing 25 or more alpha-numericals/numericals. Some of the entries do not have even one alphabet and are pure numbers.

On trying to format the cells to numbers or text, the excel converts the last 9 digits into zeros thus distorting the value.

Please suggest and help.

Comment: Don't double-click the CSV from an Explorer window; import the CSV as described below or use the [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options.

- Instead of opening the CSV file with File > Open, try using Data > From Text. This will start the import wizard, where in Step 3 you can select each column and define it as Text. This will store the numeric characters as text and will retain each character.
- Use Power Query to get the data. Power Query is a free add-in for Excel 2010 and 2013 and is built into Excel 2016 as "Get & Transform". You can load the CSV file and define the data type of each column. Each step taken to set up the query will be recorded in a script. Once set up, the query can be refreshed and the script is run. This approach is especially suitable if the import happens repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solved it. Can we keep the default settings as "text" in excel ?

Comment: Not as an application setting. If you use Power Query, the setting will be retained in the query.